# How to check if a 3 dimensional point lies in a Polygon with 4 vertices

Tags: geometry, 3d

Can anyone provide an equation to this problem?

Given that I have a 3 dimensional polygon that consist of 4 vertices, how do I check if pointX lies inside that polygon?

Comment: Four given vertices in ${\mathbb R}^3$ do not determine a polygon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's start with an example. If you want to define a segment $AB$ you can start from $A$ and add the vector $B-A$ (this is the vector going from $A$ to B) multiplied for a coefficient $t$ between $0$ and $1$ to get every point of the segment. So your segment can be described as

$A + t(B-A) = A(1-t) + tB$.

As you can see, the sum of the coefficients for $A$ and $B$ is $1$. Now given a new point $C$, you want to check if it is inside the segment or not. Notice that $A,B,C$ are know (for example are expressed with their coordinates in 3-dimensional space), so in order to check if $C$ is inside $AB$ or not, you just have to pose

$A(1-t) + tB = C$

and find $0 \leq t \leq 1$. If you can find $t$, the point is inside, if you can't it is not.

Let's do the same with our problem: Let $ABCD$ be the vertices of your polyedron. If you think at $D$ as the starting point, you can create your polyedron by adding to D any combination of vectors $DA$, $DB$, $DC$, multiplied respectively for coefficients $a,b,c$ between $0$ and $1$. So our polyedron is

$D + a(A-D) + b(B-D) +c(C-D) = aA + bB + cC + (1-a-b-c)D$.

with $a+b+c = 1$. Given a new point $Q = (x,y,z)$, is it inside?
If you express $A,B,C$ and $D$ with their coordinates and solve

aA + bB + cC + (1-a-b-c)D = (x,y,z)

if you can find $a,b,c$ which are all between $0$ and $1$ and $a+b+c = 1$
the point is inside, otherwise it is not.

EXAMPLE:

Let $D = (0,0,0)$, A = (1,0,0), B = (0,1,0), C = (0,0,1) the vertex of our polyedron. We can write our polyedron in this way

P = aA + bB + cC + (1-a-b-c)D = (a,b,c).

with $a+b+c = 1$, and $0 \leq a,b,c \leq 1$.

Is a new point $Q = (1/2,1/3,1/2)$ inside? We must solve

(a,b,c) = (1/2,1/3,1/2)

which is $a = 1/2$, $b= 1/3$, $c=1/2$ they are all in the range, but $a+b+c = 4/3 \not = 1$ so $Q$ is not inside.

Is a new point $Z=(1/3,1/3,1/3)$ insiede? We must solve

(a,b,c) = (1/3,1/3,1/3)

which is $a = 1/3$, $b= 1/3$, $c=1/3$ they are between $0$ and $1$, and their sum is $1$, so $Z$ is inside the polyedron.

Comment: Let's assume I have the polygon ABCD, which is an irregular 3d polygon. And I generate a random point (x,y,z). How do I check if that point lies within the polygon?

Comment: First of all it is called Polyhedron. You talk about the first one in the upper right corner on wikipedia i guess right? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polyhedron

Comment: As I said, rewrite that equation in terms of vectors of 3-space. If you can solve the linear system in 3 equations, finding $a,b,c$ which are between 0 and 1 the point is inside, otherwise it is not.

Comment: Can you show me a solution for this?

http://i02i.imgup.net/Captureafca.PNG

Comment: I just edited the whole solution, i hope this is more clear now!

Comment: Unfortunately I don't think this apply to your case, cause this is a polygon for real! The third coordinate doesn't exist because it is $0$ for every point. This is a problem in the plane and the polygon generated could be not convex, thus this doesn't apply! You should be more precise next time when you pose a question!

Comment: If you can have not convex polygons, I don't think you can find a general solution. You can try to post a new question posing it more precisely!

Comment: The method I showed you can be used when you are dealing with a 3D pyramid, generated by $4$ points in the space, not when they are in the same plane and generate a polygon.